# cellForItemAtIndexPath is not called when collectionVIew is reload

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using UICollectionView which has WebView. I have created CollectionView programmatically with UICollectionViewFlowLayout, like this

```
        collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
        collectionView1 = UICollectionView(frame: screenBounds, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
```

when scrollView of webView reached to bottom, There is an API call which fetch some Html data and shows in WebView and here i am reloading collectionView here in main thread, but for first 2 times it doesnt call any method in UICollectionVIewDataSource or Delegate,but on third time i calls all function, I am not sure what cause this incorrect behaviour till now collectionView1  has only one cell.

i have set the UIWebViewDelegate like this

```
public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomReaderCell
        cell.webView.scrollView.delegate = self


}
```

function where i m calling API

```
    extension CustomReaderViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate
    {
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) 
    {
             if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) ) 
     {
           // Reached To Bottom
            // Calling API here 
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.callAPI()
            })



    }
    }
    }
```

And when receive the result, reloading the collectionView

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.collectionView1.reloadData()

            }
```

Comment: can you share the whole code where you want to reload the collection view?

Comment: is collectionview delegate `sizeforItem` method getting called?

Comment: check **UICollectionView** delegate set or not
`collectionView1.delegate = self; collectionView1.dataSource = self;`

Comment: @iAviator , sizeForItemAtIndexPath is also called when collectionView reload first time, and when I reload the collectionView it doesnt call for first two times, and third time it get call

Comment: @AntonyRaphel , I have set its delegate on viewDidLoad

Comment: @KomalKamble dispatch the update to the main thread immediately after receiving the result from the API, `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
})`

Comment: @Ram, I have updated question.

Comment: Hi @KomalKamble Did you check
`// tell the collection view how many cells to make
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }` returns correctly for first two calls?

Comment: @arunjos007 yes .It has not zero value. and this calls on first time without problem and not on 2nd and 3rd time, but fourth time

Comment: @KomalKamble If you don't mind please share your project with me then surely I can help you

Comment: @arunjos007 sure how?

Comment: My mail id is arunjos007@gmail.com

Comment: I am using xcode 7.3. is it ok if i mail u then?. i

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136133/discussion-between-arunjos007-and-komal-kamble).